# could not initialize proxy - no Session in jax-ws + hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jaxb, jax-ws

I stuck in exposing web service using JAX-WS. Problem occur due to JAXB tries to serialize object after hibernate closing the session. I Google during last two days but couldn't come up with proper answer. Following are some sort of solutions given by others.

- Eager load objects
- Use @XmlTransient
- SOAPHandler but it's not completed answer

Here is the scenario in detail. I wrote one model class which has number of @OneTOMany relationships, @ManyToOne relationship and @OneToOne relationship. Web service returning object of that class as a result. When I call the service through SOAP UI it gives me the following error message.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>could not initialize proxy - no Session</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Model class (without getters and setters)

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "mas_form_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "tenantId", column = @Column(name = "mas_form_tenant_id")) })
@FilterDef(name = "tenantFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "tenantIdParam", type = "string"))
@Filters(@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "mas_form_tenant_id = :tenantIdParam"))
@Table(name = "mas_form")
public class Form extends BaseRevolution {

    @Column(name = "mas_form_action")
    private String formAction;
    @Column(name = "mas_form_is_active")
    private boolean isActive;
    @Column(name = "mas_form_is_lock")
    private boolean isLock;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mas_ft_id")
    private FormType formType;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = FORM)
    private List<FormQuestion> formQuestions = new ArrayList<FormQuestion>(0);
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = FORM)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Set<DocumentRequired> documentRequiredSet = new HashSet<DocumentRequired>(0);
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = FORM)
    private List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<Application>(0);
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = FORM)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<FormField> formFields = new ArrayList<FormField>(0);
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = FORM)
    private List<FormCharge> formCharges = new ArrayList<FormCharge>(0);
    @Column(name = "mas_form_method")
    private String formMethod;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = FORM)
    private List<FormFieldGroup> formFieldGroup;
    @Column(name = "mas_form_name_en")
    private String formNameEn;
    @Column(name = "mas_form_name_si")
    private String formNameSi;
    @Column(name = "mas_form_name_ta")
    private String formNameTa;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "activity")
    private ElgActivity elgActivity;
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 1000)
    private String description;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Web service interface

```
@WebService(name = "formWebServicePort", targetNamespace = "http://lk.gov.elg/core/ws/form/")
public interface FormWebService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "getAllFormsWithDocumentReferences", action = "urn:GetAllFormsWithDocumentReferences")
    @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
    @WebResult(name = "formsWithDocumentReferences")
    List<Form> getAllFormsWithDocumentReferences(
            @WebParam(name = "tenantId", targetNamespace = "http://lk.gov.elg/core/ws/form/") String tenantId,
            @WebParam(name = "categoryName", targetNamespace = "http://lk.gov.elg/core/ws/form/") String categoryName);
}
```

Web service implementation

```
@SchemaValidation
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://lk.gov.elg/core/ws/form/", endpointInterface = "lk.gov.elg.core.ws.citizen.FormWebService")
public class FormWebServiceImpl extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements FormWebService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FormWebServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private FormService formService;

    @Override
    public List<Form> getAllFormsWithDocumentReferences(
            @WebParam(name = "tenantId", targetNamespace = "http://lk.gov.elg/core/ws/form/") String tenantId,
            @WebParam(name = "categoryName", targetNamespace = "http://lk.gov.elg/core/ws/form/") String categoryName) {

        List<Form> formList = formService.getAllFormsWithDocRefs(tenantId, categoryName);
        return formList;
    }
}
```

Help me to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried initializing the Collections of the Form entity before exiting the session. This causes the collections to be loaded. So basicaly it does the same eager loading should do but somehow eager loading is not always helping. I can dig up more detail on this later or tomorrow if needed.

Comment: Hi Carsten, I need more detail on this. Please help. What I got from you reply is we need to call the getter method of Collection before it return Form entity. Is that so ??? Thanks.

Comment: Yep that is about right. You would initialize the collection before leaving the session/transaction by calling Hibernate.initialize(Form.getAnyCollection()); At least thats what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: we recently overcame this by adding an (EJB3) interceptor method to the sessionbean (we're using JBoss7):

```
@javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke
public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Object result = ctx.proceed();

        // Add code here to inspect the result and initialize all collections.

        return result;
}
```